# network manager: the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job

Tags: networking

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

My wired connection did not work. I edited the config files and I restarted network-manager with: `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`. The connection started, but it said te following:

```
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service network-manager restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop network-manager ; start network-manager. The restart(8) utility is also available.
```

Why is it saying that? What it can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You needn't do anything. The message is simply telling you that there is a newer and a bit easier way to do what you are trying to do:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And that you may also take a two step approach:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo service network-manager start
```